# Android Studio cannot resolve symbol BaseDemoActivity

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm trying to run some Google Drive sample code from the Android Developers website but I'm getting a number of instances where Android Studio cannot resolve method. I think most of the problem might be attributed to BaseDemoActivity also not being recognized. I've gone through the setup process to make sure I have everything correct and as far as I can see it is, I even just this morning updated my Google Play Services version in case it was that but still nothing. Can someone point me in the right direction of how I might fix this?

```
/**
 * An activity to illustrate how to create a new folder.
 */
public class CreateFolderActivity extends BaseDemoActivity {

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    super.onConnected(connectionHint);
    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
            .setTitle("New folder").build();
    Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient()).createFolder(
            getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet).addResultCallback(folderCreatedCallback);
}

ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult> folderCreatedCallback = new
        ResultCallback<DriveFolderResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DriveFolderResult result) {
        if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            showMessage("Error while trying to create the folder");
            return;
        }
        showMessage("Created a folder: " + result.getDriveFolder().getDriveId());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BaseDemoActivity is not part of the API, its just used in the samples.  Make sure you have that class copied into your app from the sample.